# The s3 send a message to SQS with which role?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

When I create a SQS in an aws account `A` to accept the s3(in `B` account) message when s3 files was changed.

I need to set who can send message to the SQS I created. I don't know which role the s3 using to send message.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your situation is:

- **Account A** has an SQS queue.
- **Account B** has an Amazon S3 bucket with an Event configured to send a notification to the SQS queue in Account A when a file is changed.

You will need to **add a policy to the SQS queue** to accept an event from the S3 bucket. Copy the sample policy from the documentation (link below) and add the ARN (Amazon Resource Name) of the SQS queue and the name of the S3 bucket. (I tested it -- it works!)

See documentation: [Granting Permissions to Publish Event Notification Messages to a Destination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#grant-destinations-permissions-to-s3)